# WP e-commerce. counting the number of product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I'm using the WP e-Commerce plugin and am currently trying to build a sitemap page for the product categories.

Thing is, there are quite a number of these categories so I wanted to split them into two columns.

I got a code snippet from http://spruce.it/noise/good-old-2-column-loop-in-wordpres/

Logically it seems like it'll work except that it's counting posts instead of categories.

And obviously from the markup below, I'm not sure what I'm doing.

```
<?php 

$catquery = wpsc_start_category_query(
    array(
        'category_group' = >get_option('wpsc_default_category'), 
        'show_thumbnails'=> get_option('show_category_thumbnails')
    )
); 

$i = 0; 
if ($i == 0) echo '<div class="tri2"><ul>';
if ($i == (round($catquery->post_count / 2))) echo '</ul></div><div class="tri2"><ul>'; //this is where it probably fails 

?>
<li> 
    <a href="<?php wpsc_print_category_url();?>" class="wpsc_category_link <?php wpsc_print_category_classes_section(); ?>" title="<?php wpsc_print_category_name(); ?>">
        <?php wpsc_print_category_name(); ?>
    </a>

    <?php if(wpsc_show_category_description()) :?>
        <?php //wpsc_print_category_description("<div class='wpsc_subcategory'>", "</div>"); ?>
    <?php endif;?>

    <?php wpsc_print_subcategory("<ul>", "</ul>"); ?>
</li>

<?php 
if ($i == round($catquery->post_count)) echo '</ul></div>';;
$i++;
wpsc_end_category_query(); 
?>
```

Trying to make sense out of it, I do believe i just need to be able to get the total number of categories. right? but how do I do that though.

Comment: in any case, i decided to go around by using jQuery to segment the category list to 2 columns. i am hoping to achieve that result with php though..

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is trying to get the number of product categories, this can be achieved quite simply with the WordPress function, [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)().

```
<?php
    $list_args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'style' => 'list',
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'show_count' => true,
        );

    $cat_array = get_categories($list_args);

    //This will be the number of categories.
    $category_count = 0;

    foreach($cat_array as $val){
        $category_count++;
    }

?>
```